# Reloading page with PHP? Selected form option not updated after being output by PHP, visually locked until the URL is re-input (not just refreshed)

Tags: php, html

I want to have a random default selected option in a "select" form.

For this, there is an array with the value of each option, a random number is generated, and then, when going through the array with a "for" loop, if the current option matches the random number, this option will be the default ("selected"):

```
$signs = array("+", "-", "·", "/", "^", "V");
$shown = array("+", "-", "·", "/", "^", "&#x2713;");
                
$num = rand(0, 5);
echo $num;
                
echo '<select name="sign" id="sign">';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($signs); $i++)
{
    echo '<option value="' . $signs[$i] . '"';
    if ($num == $i)
    {
        echo ' selected';
    }
    echo '>' . $shown[$i] . '</option>';
    echo $i;
}
echo '</select>';
```

The code output is correct, options are selected randomly. However, the visual aspect of the "select" form input does not change.

Reloading the page does not change it, but re-entering the URL does. What to do?

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="recogedatos.php" method="POST">
                <?php
                    echo '<input type="number" id="num1" name="num1" value="';
                    echo rand(0, 100);
                    echo '" readonly="readonly">';
                    
                    $signs = array("+", "-", "·", "/", "^", "V");
                    $shown = array("+", "-", "·", "/", "^", "&#x2713;");
                    
                    
                    $num = rand(0, 5);
                    echo $num;
                    
                    echo '<select name="sign" id="sign">';
                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($signs); $i++)
                        {
                            echo '<option value="' . $signs[$i] . '"';
                            if ($num == $i)
                            {
                                echo ' selected';
                            }
                            echo '>' . $shown[$i] . '</option>';
                            echo $i;
                        }
                    echo '</select>';
                    
                    echo '<input type="number" id="num2" name="num2" value="';
                    echo rand(0, 100);
                    echo '" readonly="readonly">';
                ?>
                =
                <input type="number" id="num3" name="num3">
                
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could select a random option using JavaScript on the client side ... If you execute that functionality on page load, then it should work after a simple reload as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue might be related to browser caching or the form retaining its state. You can try to disable caching and/or reset the form.

```php
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- rest of your code -->
```

Adding these headers at the beginning of your PHP file should instruct the browser not to cache the page. This way, each time you reload the page, the PHP script should execute again, potentially resolving your issue.

Comment: Sadly didn't solve the problem. I should add that if I select manually any of the options of the drop-down list, it also stays selected across refreshes, and changes when hitting the direction in the address bar.

Comment: What if you add `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the `<form>` or `<select>` tag to prevent this?

Comment: This solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Ahhhh... yes. The little things. =)